# Express.js not rerouting to maintenance page on default request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to reroute the user to a maintenance page while I work on a site, but for some reason it only does it if I have something except the base URL in the browser. Example: on a client if I go to `http://example.com/` it will load the page, but if I go to `http://example.com/somewhere-else` it will correctly reroute to the maintenance page. How can I listen to and catch ALL HTTP requests, regardless of path, and route them properly? `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` represents my IP address. I've tested this on my computer and on my phone with wifi switched off (using cellular).

```
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

    app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
        return res.send('pong');
    });

    app.get('*', function (req, res) {
        var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
        if (ip.substr(0, 7) == "::ffff:") {
            ip = ip.substr(7)
        }

        if (ip == "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx") {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
        }
        else {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'construction.html'));
        }
    });

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, change the following

```
app.get('*' to app.get('/'
```

Then, it should redirect all the default calls to maintenance page.

Comment: This didn't fix it.